# Change Icon after clicking it and also when we click on other button in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to change the Icon when i click on it and also when i press another button.

Current situation: i m able to change the icon using .toggle but unable to figure out way to change it when i press another button.

Code:

HTML:

```
<a link=# onClick="someOtherFunction()">Change Icon by Click</a>
<br>
<button class="mail_btn click" onclick= "someOtherFunction(); changeIcon();">
            <i id ='mailBTN' class="fa-solid fa-envelope envelope" onclick="changeIcon(this)"></i>

            <!-- this is the icon i want 
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope-open-text">
              </i> -->

</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeIcon(icon){
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-envelope-open-text');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your  element by using Javascript getElementById method.

```
function anotherButtonClick() {
  var el = document.getElementById("mailBTN");
  el.classList.toggle('fa-envelope-open-text');
}
```

Then you can toggle your classList as you did for other button before.

Comment: thank you, it works when i dont add '.nativeElement'

Comment: Alright. I edited the answer.